# Python Flask_SQLAlchemy query.order_by(time)

Tags: python, database, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to sort data in a database by the time.  I am utilizing the flask_sqlalchemy tool.

The database that I'm trying to order by the time is initialized with this class:

```
class Weather(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'weather'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    time = db.Column(db.DateTime, unique=True, nullable=False)
    weather = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Weather %r>' % self.id
```

In this class, I'm gettin data from the open source http://api.openweathermap.org/.  I know that the code to retrieve the data works because I can visualize it on my Flask app.  However, when I query it with `weather = Weather.query.order_by(Weather.time).all()` I want the data to be ordered by the time of the DateTime object, instead it's just stuck ordering it by the date.  If anyone can help I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Do you want all 12:00pm to be ordered together, regardless of date? How do you want to determine the order of X results that are all 12:00pm?

Comment: @RyanH, yes I'm trying to group like all the 12:00pm together regardless of time.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
weather = Weather.query.order_by(extract('hour', Weather.time)).all()
```